# splitting image and merging

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing

I have a polygon points like below:

```
geometry = [
    [
      [
        38.752152,
        37.208675
      ],
      [
        39.224913,
        37.208675
      ],
      [
        39.224913,
        36.686262
      ],
      [
        38.752152,
        36.686262
      ],
      [
        38.752152,
        37.208675
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I take an image by this coordinates and assume its size is 5000x5000. I want to split it into four images that their sizes are 2500x2500 and merge them. To do that, I split the geometry into some pieces by sampling it until reach maximum value of the coordinates.

```
step_x = round(size[0]/2500+1)
step_y = round(size[1]/2500+1)
points_x = numpy.linspace(x_min,x_max,step_x)
points_y = numpy.linspace(y_min,y_max,step_y)
combinedImage = numpy.zeros((step_x*2500,step_y*2500,3)) #To merge the images
```

Then I get images from an api

```
size_x = len(points_x)
size_y = len(points_y)




for y in range(size_y-1):
    for x in range(size_x-2,-1,-1):
        tmpGeometry = [[[points_x[x],points_y[y]],[points_x[x+1],points_y[y]],[points_x[x],points_y[y+1]],[points_x[x+1],points_y[y+1]]]]
        x_min, y_min = numpy.min(tmpGeometry, axis = 1)[0]#like left top coordinates.
        x_max, y_max = numpy.max(tmpGeometry, axis = 1)[0]#like right bottom coordinates.
        sentinelhub.setBBox(x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max)
        image = sentinelhub.sendRequest()# I got image at here
        combinedImage[2500*y:2500*(y+1),2500*x:2500*(x+1)] = image# I try to merge the images
      
        print((x,y),(x,y+1),(x+1,y),(x+1,y+1))
```

After everything is done, I get image but it is little bit mixed, look at red lines. It is like two part, top and bottom part and their place are wrong. On the top one should be bottom  and on the bottom should be top.

[image]

Comment: please prepare a [mre].

Comment: maybe you should merge in different order.

Comment: @furas I tried all orders that I know.

Comment: maybe put every image on separated canvas and write in separated file - so you could see what you really try to merge

Answer (score -1):

My problem was solved when I change my code with that:

```
for y in range(size_y-1):
    images = []
    rows = []
    for x in range(size_x-1):
        tmpGeometry = [[[points_x[x],points_y[y]],[points_x[x],points_y[y+1]],[points_x[x+1],points_y[y]],[points_x[x+1],points_y[y+1]]]]
        x_min, y_min = numpy.min(tmpGeometry, axis = 1)[0]
        x_max, y_max = numpy.max(tmpGeometry, axis = 1)[0]
        sentinelhub.setBBox(x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max)
        image = sentinelhub.getCombinedImage()
        rows.append(image)

        
    
        print((x,y),(x,y+1),(x+1,y),(x+1,y+1))
    rows = numpy.concatenate(rows, axis = 1)
    images.append(rows)


images = images[::-1]
images = numpy.concatenate(images,axis =0)
cv2.imwrite("concatenate.jpg",images)
```